# Send data with Scapy

Tags: hex, scapy

I want to send payload which is in the form of hex value with Scapy, the hex format is like this: `\xe3\x00\xfa` and go on but the hex value I have is like `x0ba324de` ... How can I convert it to the group of two by two with `\x` in front of it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try that (using python):

```
>>> x = '0ba324de'
>>> y = x.decode('hex')
>>> y
'\x0b\xa3$\xde'
```

and to revert back:

```
>>> y.encode('hex')
'0ba324de'
```